# How to grant user User Points after publishing content, while content's default is unpublished?

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints

I'd like to grant users User Points when their added content of the content type 'Content', which is unpublished by default, is published. I tried this with the Rules module:
- Event: After saving new content
- Elements:
  * Content is of type: Content
  * Content is published
- Actions: Grant points to a user

So, when a user adds 'Content' content, they don't get any User Points and their content is unpublished. My idea was that they'd be granted the points after I - as moderator - had published their content. But apparently, they don't get points after I've done that with the rule I set up. What did I do wrong and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing this:

1. Create [flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) and give flag name as **Publish node and grant points to user**
2. Add new rule with event **A node has been flagged, under "Publish node and grant points to user"**
3. For actions **publish this node** and **grant points to user** use this data `selector: flagged-node:author`

Special thanks to oneng on Stackoverflow!